# How to access virtual field in controller instead of model entity in cakephp 3.2

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.2

I have implemented virtual filed in model/entity/Order.php .

But i want to access for one page only ,i don't want it to be called for all the functions .So in controller how can i access virtual field so that it will be applicable for only the portion i need.

In cakephp 2x version ,i have made for controller ,but this time in 3X i am unable to make it.

below i have attached some codes

Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thank you .

Model/Entity/Order.php

```html
 protected $_virtual = ['amount'];

    protected function _getAmount() {


            $data = [];
            $data['due'] = $this->_properties['collection']['due_amount'];
            $data['paid'] = $this->_properties['collection']['total_sale_amount'] - $this->_properties['collection']['due_amount'];
            return $data;
        }
```

Codes in controller

```html
   $Lists = $this->Orders->find('all')->where($condition)->contain(['Collections','Customers'=> ['queryBuilder' => function ($q) {
                               return $q->select(['id','center_name']);
                              }],])->order(['Orders.due_date ASC']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used getter method of entity by declaring function `_get*`. Your getter method name is `_getAmount()`, so you can access this by entity object in controller $entity->amount();

```
$Lists = $this->Orders->find('all')->where($condition)->contain(['Collections','Customers'=> ['queryBuilder' => function ($q) {
                               return $q->select(['id','center_name']);
                              }],])->order(['Orders.due_date ASC']);

// Iteration will execute the query.
foreach ($Lists as $entity) {
        echo $entity->amount;
}
```

Check document about [virtual field in CakePHP 3.x](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#creating-virtual-fields)

Also no need of below line in Entity, so remove it, because you are using getter method.

```
protected $_virtual = ['amount'];
```

Comment: But its throwing some error like Error: Call to undefined method App\Model\Entity\Order::amount()

Comment: can you debug ($entity) in foreach loop which type of object it has?

Comment: Ok sure. I will

Comment: ohh.. use `$entity->amount` instead of `$entity->amount()`

Comment: yes i got it, but one more problem ,how to get it in one array.
I mean the result should be merge with the main array individually .
So that it is easy to access for me.

Comment: which result you are talking about its a return from _getAmount() or query result into array? if you want to query result in array then `$Lists = $this->Orders->find('all')->where($condition)->contain(['Collections','Customers'=> ['queryBuilder' => function ($q) {
                               return $q->select(['id','center_name']);
                              }],])->order(['Orders.due_date ASC'])->toArray();`

Also you need to undertand concept of Entity in CakePHP v3.x

Comment: I want it should be come like [
    {
        "id": 20,     
        "customer": {
            "id": 5,
            "center_name": "Vision Care Eye Hospital"
        },
        "collection": {
            "id": 150,
            "order_id": 20,
            "total_sale_amount": 110,
            "net_paid": 10,
            "due_amount": 70,
            "is_paid": 1,
            "payment_mode": "DD",
            "reference_num": "",
            "created": "2016-09-09T00:00:00+0000"
        },
        "amount": {
            "due": 70,
            "paid": 40
        }
    },

Comment: You can Convert entity into array by using `$entity->toArray()`, but unfortunately you can't wrap virtual field in to array

Comment: yes i want to wrap it.
Previously i have wrpped the virtual fields ,but while in controller ,i am getting the result ,but i need the wrapping section .

Comment: I got the basic idea .Thank you.
I accepted your work.

Comment: is it possible to do wrapping??
i need it urgently.

Comment: in new version v3  it not possible you can retrive protected and vritual fields only through Entity object not from Array